# ReadLine is changing the text read?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I have a text file that I need to read and modify.  This file come from another program so I can not modify its format. I need to use it as a template and make a bunch of replacements for specific cases. One of the lines I am reading is delimited with 0xFF characters. But when I call ReadLine the string returns the line delimited with 0x3F characters.  I have tried different encodings. ASCII where it comes back as 0x3f and UTF-8 where it comes back as 3bytes 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD.  The original text file seems to be ANSI format and the 0xFF character shows up as a "ÿ". How can I get my ReadLine (and the subsequent WriteLine) to keep this character intact?

```
   var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"to_replace1", "replacement1"}, {"to_replace2", "replacement2"}, {"etc etc", "more replaces"} };

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(projectfileSpecific, false, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
      foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(projectfileTemplate, Encoding.ASCII))
      {
        foreach (var replacement in replacements)
        {
          if (line.Contains(replacement.Key))
          {
            var replaceLine = line;
            writer.WriteLine(replaceLine.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value));
          }
          else
          {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are other encodings. Perhaps `Encoding.Default` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` will do it? Check out the `GetEncodings` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings.aspx. ASCII won't do it, as it's a 7-bit encoding. And UTF-8 won't do because characters with high bits set are combining character.

Comment: @Jim Mischel - thank you!  "ISO-8859-1" worked perfectly.  I didn't realize you could specify other encodings this way.